# Angular ngFor adicionar condicional usnado ng-content

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou usando primeng para renderizar dados numa tabela, segue conforme documentação meus dados e minha config de colunas

```
   API {
      id: 1,
      nome: "Test 1",
      moeda: "Euro",
      status: "Recebido",
      data: "01/01/1999",
    }

 ngOnInit {
   this.col = [
     {field: 'nome', header: 'Nome'},
     {field: 'moeda',  header: 'Moeda'},
     {field: 'status', header: 'Status'},
     {field: 'data', header: 'Data'}
   ]
}
```

Bom, faço um ngFor e renderinzo cada coluna e seus respectivos dados com sucesso

```
<td *ngFor="let col of column">
    {{rowData[col.field]}}
</td>
```

Agora o problema, para cada coluna de dados na inha tabela preciso formatar de acordo, por exemplo, a coluna Data precisa usar um pipe para formar da data, para outros campos preciso fazer outras alterações, podendo usar pipe.

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns | keyvalue">
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] !== 'data'"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] === 'data'"> {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}</ng-container>
</td>
```

Como que eu faço por exemplo nesse contexto acima se eu tiver que também usar pipe de uppercase na coluna nome, ou tiver que usar pipe de currency na coluna moeda como que faço par renderizar tudo isso dentro de um ng-container.

Se for data teria que vir com data formatada, se for nome em uppercase, se for moeda com currency, enfim como faço refactoy desse codigo abaixo?

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns | keyvalue">
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] !== 'data'"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] === 'data'"> {{rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd/MMM/yyyy'}}
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] !== 'moeda'"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] === 'moeda'"> {{rowData[col.field] | currency:'CAD':'code'}'}}
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] !== 'nome'"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="rowData[col.field] === 'nome'"> {{rowData[col.field] | uppercase}}</ng-container>
</td>
```

Comment: Sua dúvida não ficou clara!

Comment: Porque não criar um método no componente que devolve os dados no formato correto e apenas chamar ele direto ?

Comment: @LeAndrade preciso rendericar cada item do array, porém cada itém tem que adicionar um pipe para modificar o valor, por exemplo se eu não fosse modificar nada so renderizar, bastava apenas colocar {{ rowData[col.field }}, mas como cada item do array eu preciso fazer modificação, estou procurando um meio de fazer isso!